# How to Add unallocated partition to my root dir

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I need add unallocated part to `/dev/sda6` to extend the root partition. These are the partitions on my drive

[image]

Comment: Try to increase root partition /dev/sda6 to all unallocated place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **move** sda6 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of sda6 all the way right
- click the Apply icon

Answer (score 0):

Please boot your system using a USB live Ubuntu system and use gparted to expand the /dev/sda6 for the unallocated space.